# Accessing user info through Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Scenario - Frontend will login to microsoft and will give access token to backend, with that token I am unable to create microsoft graph api instance.

I am trying to access the user data using microsoft graph api and I receive this error.

```
Status Code: Unauthorized
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-09-30T11:00:43
    request-id: -8561--aebc-ff72e69942c4
    client-request-id: -8561-4fb2-aebc-
ClientRequestId: c4f169bb-8561-4fb2-aebc-

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at OptimusPortal.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetAsync() in C:\Users\bippan.kumar\Documents\GitHub\OIC\OptimusPortal\OptimusPortal\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs:line 52
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My ConfigureServices function in Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            string token;
            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated
                };

                options.Authority += "/v2.0";
                options.Audience = "api://xyz";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    //I have kept these settings in place to provide easy support for docker.
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Function where I am creating GraphServiceClient instance. Error is thrown at last line of code in this function.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAsync()
        {
            var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
            new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            })
            );

            // Make a Microsoft Graph API query
            // Error is thrown at this line of code
            var users = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide full correlation id and timestamp

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to access the Graph API on behalf of a user. Keep in mind there is also a way to access without a user using a different workflow. Remember you need to register the app with Entra ID (previously Azure AD). Then you need to configure Graph client for user authentication:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail;

class GraphHelper
{
    // Settings object
    private static Settings? _settings;
    // User auth token credential
    private static DeviceCodeCredential? _deviceCodeCredential;
    // Client configured with user authentication
    private static GraphServiceClient? _userClient;
    
    public static void InitializeGraphForUserAuth(Settings settings,
        Func<DeviceCodeInfo, CancellationToken, Task> deviceCodePrompt)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        
        var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
        {
            ClientId = settings.ClientId,
            TenantId = settings.TenantId,
            DeviceCodeCallback = deviceCodePrompt,
        };
    
        _deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);

        _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(_deviceCodeCredential,                         
            settings.GraphUserScopes);
    }
    
    public static async Task<string> GetUserTokenAsync()
    {
        // Ensure credential isn't null
        _ = _deviceCodeCredential ?? throw new 
            System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been " +
                "initialized for user auth");

        // Ensure scopes isn't null
        _ = _settings?.GraphUserScopes ?? throw new             
            System.ArgumentNullException("Argument 'scopes' cannot " + 
                "be null");

        // Request token with given scopes
        var context = new TokenRequestContext(_settings.GraphUserScopes);
        var response = await _deviceCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(context);
        return response.Token;
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
void InitializeGraph(Settings settings)
{
    GraphHelper.InitializeGraphForUserAuth(settings,
        (info, cancel) =>
        {
            // Display the device code message to
            // the user. This tells them
            // where to go to sign in and provides the
            // code to use.
            Console.WriteLine(info.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
}

async Task DisplayAccessTokenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var userToken = await GraphHelper.GetUserTokenAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"User token: {userToken}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user access token: " +
            "{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3